# Bootstrap paginator css not appearing

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5

I am following this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928) to create a table in php with bootstrap styling.

Using the reference in bootstrap as `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`
allows me to see the table with the correct format but the paginator (included below) is not appearing in the correct css:
[image].

How i can make the bootstrap css style appear?

**Reference code**

Paginator code called by the function `<?php echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' ); ?>`:

```
public function createLinks( $links, $list_class ) {
    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        return '';
    }


$last       = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

$start      = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links : 1;
$end        = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page + $links : $last;

$html       = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

$class      = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
$html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

if ( $start > 1 ) {
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=1">1</a></li>';
    $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
}

for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
    $class  = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
    $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}

if ( $end < $last ) {
    $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
}

$class      = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
$html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

$html       .= '</ul>';

return $html;
}
}
```

Comment: `bootstrap-4`? You're using Bootstrap5! What does the resulting HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the generated HTML missing some of the neccessary Bootstrap classes.

Even though you correctly set the pagination class to the `<ul>` element, I think you are missing classes in `<li>` and `<a>` elements.

This is how it should look like based on [BS docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/pagination/):

```
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Try adding `.page-item` class to `<li>` element and `.page-link` class `<a>` element into your PHP function so it generates correct HTML and you should be fine.

Comment: you were right, missed some classes in the li and a, just need to put them in the php function